# comparison of generalize linear mixed effect models in R with compare_performance function

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, model, model-comparison

Below I add my model comparison between a random intercept and random slope model using performance library. I used compare_performance. My models are:

```
mylogit_inst <- glmer(success ~ inst + (1|fish_ID), 
                      data = results, family = "binomial")
mylogit_s <- glmer(success ~ inst_diff + (1+inst_diff|fish_ID), 
                   data = results, family = "binomial")
```

What kinds of assumptions can be made based on the image? Usually, in model comparisons (I checked many sources), the AIC is commonly used as the comparison factor. If the AIC value is lower, it indicates a better model. Then can we say mylogit_s is better than mylogit_inst? I would appreciate if someone can make a comment or guide me a source where I can find other examples.

[image]